# How I can add a shadow to a texture on SDL2?

Tags: c++, sdl-2

So, I'm making a 2D game and I have some textures. I will like some of them to drop a shadow, there is something like drop-shadow in css for SDL2?

Comment: Probably with another texture that looks like a shadow.

Comment: but how I can make that texture? I will like the shadow to have the same shape

Comment: You could draw it, or write code to draw it for you

Answer (score 3):

Since noone mentionned it yet, here it is:

```
int SDL_SetTextureColorMod(SDL_Texture* texture,
                           Uint8        r,
                           Uint8        g,
                           Uint8        b)
```

https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetTextureColorMod

This function multiplies a texture color channels when copying it to the SDL_Renderer*. Using it with 0 as r, g and b arguments would make your texture pitch black but not affect the alpha, so the texture would keep its shape (like in the case of a transparent PNG). You just have to copy that shadow before (= behind) your texture, with a slight offset. You can also change the overall transparency of the shadow, with `SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod(SDL_Texture* texture, Uint8 a)`

Just don't forget to set the values back to 255 when you're done.

---

Code example:

```
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
// [...] draw background, etc... here

SDL_Rect characterRect;
// [...] fill the rect however you want
SDL_Rect shadowRect(characterRect);
shadowRect.x += 30; // offsets the shadow
shadowRect.y += 30;

SDL_SetTextureColorMod(characterTexture, 0, 0, 0);                // makes the texture black
SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod(characterTexture, 191);                    // makes the texture 3/4 of it's original opacity      
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, characterTexture, NULL, &shadowRect);    // draws the shadow
SDL_SetTextureColorMod(characterTexture, 255, 255, 255);          // sets the values back to normal
SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod(characterTexture, 255);
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, characterTexture, NULL, &characterRect); // draws the character

// [...] draw UI, additionnal elements, etc... here
SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
```

Answer (score 1):

Render the texture first, then render a slightly larger semi-transparent gray square slightly behind it. If you want rounded corners, [use a shader that increases alpha as you get further from the corners](https://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/distfunctions2d/distfunctions2d.htm).

Comment: oh wow, this looks really nice. I'm not sure how I should use this with SDL

Comment: Edit your question with your current code. You might need to use OpenGL shaders.

Comment: so I don't have code for this, I'm just drawing a rectangle. In the future I will use a png instead. I'm just researching.

Comment: Just fake it with grey rectangles. Make it prettier later.

Comment: okay has sense, I will try this. I'm not using opengl yet, I wonder if I will need to refactor everything later to use it

Comment: A framework like SFML will accommodate you on your journey. Get something working first with sf::Sprite and friends, then add custom rendering code later.

Comment: but I have all the input and basic stuff already working with SDL

Comment: You can use SDL for input and creating an OpenGL context and do the rest in OpenGL.

Comment: I'm searching how to do this but it doesn't seems to be something common? People mention to do this but I can't find examples

Comment: See [Creating a context with SDL](https://open.gl/context#SDL) and the rest of that tutorial series